# Buttons and preview are broken in Firefox 3.5 on SO only

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

When submitting an edit, an answer, or a question, buttons and preview won't show in FireFox 3.5 on Stack Overflow.

On Meta, Super User, and Server Fault everything's fine, as it is on SO using IE8 and Chrome.

It started today, on Aug 26th 2009, at about 13:00Z

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

The problem persists in safe mode too.

Does anybody else experience this or it is just me?

Comment: works fine for me on Firefox 3.5.2

Comment: Have you tested it in Safe Mode?

Comment: `@John`: yes, it persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you've got some cached javascript.  I don't know that there have been any updates, but you might want to try emptying your cache.  If you don't regularly use IE8 or Chrome with SO, they may have downloaded more recent code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got NoScript installed? if so you need to ensure that sstatic.net is not blocked

Comment: No, I don't    .

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems on SO and here on meta as well. The only button that works for me is the 'edit' one and 'post your answer'. I'm using Firefox 3.5.2 and this started sometime in August or late July.

--edit--
I just verified that SO does not work in IE either so maybe my network admins are blocking something.